# Аннотация типов

Tags: python, typing

Как аннотировать вложенные функции? (Декораторы и просто вложенные функции)?
В чем смысл ParamSpec?

```
from collections.abc import Callable
from typing import TypeVar, ParamSpec
import logging

T = TypeVar('T')
P = ParamSpec('P')

def add_logging(f: Callable[P, T]) -> Callable[P, T]:
'''A type-safe decorator to add logging to a function.'''
   def inner(*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs) -> T:
    logging.info(f'{f.__name__} was called')
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
return inner
```

Comment: Прежде чем задать вопрос, убедитесь, что вы выполнили тщательный поиск ответа. Поделитесь результатом вашего поиска и расскажите, что вы нашли и почему найденные ответы вас не устроили. Это продемонстрирует вашу способность думать самостоятельно, поможет избежать повторяющихся очевидных ответов и, самое важное, увеличит шансы на получение точного ответа! https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Эникейщик нашел только ParamSpec, но в документации описано очень лаконично и непонятно. Как работает данная аннотация

Comment: Приведите какие-то примеры что ли. Пока непонятно в чём собственно вопрос. Почему нельзя аннотировать вложенные функции так же, как и обычные.

Comment: @CrazyElf pep612 про ParamSpec есть пример аннотации, но не понятно как работает

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import Annotated
```

## новое в  Python 3.9.

```
Annotated[T, x]
```

T - тип данных Python

x - контекстно-зависимые метаданные типа T.

Answer (score 0):

Как я понимаю.

Декоратор `add_logging` может декорировать какие угодно функции с разным числом параметров. При этом и типы этих параметров неизвестны. И раз параметры неизвестны, то приходится описывать функцию-враппер как `*args/**kwags: object`. То есть информация о сигнатуре теряется и невозможно нормально проверять типы системой проверки типов.

`ParamSpec` позволяет "захватить" **набор** параметров, что приходит с `Callable`, и пробросить их указание возвращаемой функции путем указания типов `*args: P.args, **kwargs: P.kwargs`. Этакий generic для множества типов сразу.

Таким образом, несмотря на то что внутренняя функция имеет сигнатуру `*args/**kwags`, тайп-чекер будет знать что функция-враппер из декоратора связана с сигнатурой декорируемой функции, то есть будет знать типы параметров функции-враппера.